# Join of two subgroups example -- Question from Mac Lane and Birkhoff (Chapter II, section 4, problem 3)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Mac Lane and Birkhoff's book and working through the problems. In one of the problems we're asked to find the meet and join of all subgroups of $\mathbb Z_8$. As I was working through this problem, it just seemed too easy. So, I'm not sure if I was missing some things. If you have time to offer some feedback, I would greatly appreciate it.

First, I found that the subgroups of $\mathbb Z_8$ are $\langle e \rangle = 8\mathbb Z_8$, $\, 4\mathbb Z_8$, $\, 2\mathbb Z_8$, and $\mathbb Z_8$.

Next, finding the meet (which I've been told is the intersection), I have that since we have a chain of subgroups $8\mathbb Z_8 \subset 4\mathbb Z_8\subset 2\mathbb Z_8\subset \mathbb Z_8$, the intersection of any two subgroups is equal to the `smaller' of the two.

For example, $2\mathbb Z_8 \wedge 4\mathbb Z_8 = 4\mathbb Z_2$ (I'm using $\wedge$ for `meet.')

Next, the join. The join of two subgroups $S \vee T$ is defined by Mac Lane and Birkhoff as the smallest subgroup which contains both $S$ and $T$. For this, I found that the join of two subgroups of $\mathbb Z_8$ to be equal to the `larger' of the two subgroups.

For example, $2 \mathbb Z_8 \vee 4 \mathbb Z_8 = 2\mathbb Z_8$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks fine to me. The subgroup lattice of cyclic groups is very simple. You might try an example with a more complicated lattice, like [$D_8$](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/D4.html).

Comment: You aren’t missing anything. Here, the subgroup lattice is *totally ordered*, so that the join is the larger subgroup and the meet is the smaller subgroup, in all cases.

Comment: Many thanks!!!!